# Viber messenger API

Tags: api, messenger, viber

I'm looking for a library to do requests to Viber messenger server.
I need to:

- send messages to users;
- check sent messages delivery status;
- check that a user has Viber account.

I know that Viber has no open API for developers, but maybe someone has experience with reverse engeneering of Viber protocol or some else methods of communication with Viber.
Or if someone can do it, please, write me, I have a suggestion for you.

Comment: Well, we do have it now - https://developers.viber.com/

Comment: [Disclaimer] It's a company I work for but under the roof, we are using official Viber API. Have a look at it - https://docs.amio.io/v1.0/reference#api-viber .

Answer (score 2):

All I did was createing an applicaion for UIautomate of viber message sending using viber desktop application.
if you want to send bulk messages or messages to your contact do this way.

Comment: But uiautomator is for android only. How do you did it with viber desktop application?