# Viber API and PHP web application?

Tags: php, viber

I've a list of around 900 phone numbers of a clinic that I'm working on. I need to send a photo to those all numbers if they have viber account. Doing so for individual numbers is a pain and time consuming as well. I was wondering if I could do a simple web application that would take a list of numbers and then send the picture to those numbers through Viber

Is there any similar or simple way to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viber messenger API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125959/viber-messenger-api)